# How to load an image using JuicyPixel?

Tags: haskell

Haskell's JuicyPixel library has a function to load `png` images, `readPng`. The problem is that this function returns a `Either String DynamicImage` type, where most of the library function's actually use an Image type. The library's documentation is not clear on what is the correct method to get a proper `Image` from the result of `readPng`.

So far, this is what I have done:

```
import Codec.Picture

main = do
    imageLoad <- readPng "myImage.png"
    case imageLoad of
        Left error  -> putStrLn error
        Right image -> do
            putStrLn "success"
            case image of
                ImageY8 img     -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageY16 img    -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageYF img     -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageYA8 img    -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageYA16 img   -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageRGB8 img   -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageRGB16 img  -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageRGBF img   -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageRGBA8 img  -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageRGBA16 img -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageYCbCr8 img -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageCMYK8 img  -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
                ImageCMYK16 img -> print "TODO: deal with this case."
    print "Done."
```

Of course, I am not going to manually deal with every possible encoding, so I just (by trial and error) figured out the type of image I was getting (it was ImageRGBA8) and partially matched against it. That sounds like a very bad idea, though - is this really how it must be done, or does the library provide a proper way to just load an image on the format you ask it to?

Answer (score 4):

Well conversions aren't free so your choices are either to operate on the image in whatever format you are given or to convert.  In other words you can:

- Use polymorphic operations on dynamic images (there are a few)
- Explicitly destruct the `DynamicImage` and operate over the image with a known encoding.
- Convert whatever encoding to a single encoding for operations.

This last option seems the most straight-forward and is supported by the `JuicyPixels-utils` package.  Specifically, see the `fromDynamicImage` and `readImageRGBA8` [functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-util-0.2/docs/Codec-Picture-RGBA8.html#v:readImageRGBA8).

Comment: Note that to use polymorphic operations on dynamic images you'll have to use `dynamicMap` or `dynamicPixelMap`, those takes operations polymorphic in the `Pixel` type and apply them to a `DynamicImage`. Also note that conversion doesn't cost anything if your `DynamicImage` is of the right type in the first place (so you should chose to standardize on the most common type of image you have to handle).